# Initialising an object at class level vs inside initState

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a `TextEditingController`, and to initialise it, I can either do

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _controller = TextEditingController();
  // ...
}
```

or

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  // ...
}
```

And in both cases I can use `dispose` method to clean the `_controller`. Is there any difference between two approaches when it comes to memory allocation, will `dispose` be able to dispose the one created at class level?

Answer (score 1):

You can always refer to the widgets documentation. `TextEditingController`'s [doc sample](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html#widgets.TextEditingController.1) initializes it on creation.

There is almost no difference because initState is the first thing done after the `State` creation (see [widget lifecycle](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-q3QIpsS_kK4/Xe0iZtwshKI/AAAAAAAAA8k/_tWHPDf8JOI93IYSo8WP_6D_sIKXy_xSACLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/flutter-stateful-widget-life-cycle.png)).

**EDIT :** To answer your comment, your link is a cookbook, so it's more hands-on and less in the theory. Also, it can be dirty or broken apparently, which you can find out if you scroll to the bottom.

I feel your pain about documentation, a lot of the times you get clearer info from "unofficial" sources. You can still refer to it though, but yeah you have to keep that critical spirit.

Anyway, the cleanest way is to initialize on creation, if you can. Initialization in `initState` is typically done when you need the `BuildContext` or some extra business logic beforehand.

Comment: Docs always have been confusing no matter which framework you're using. For instance, when you see [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus), you'll find they initialise `FocusNode` in `initState`, and there is nothing in `initState` besides the initialisation, so why didn't they do initialisation at the class level? Seems like there is some difference.